# Why return in function suppress the exception raised?

Tags: python, exception

Check the following code about exception processing in python

```
class myException(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'this is my exception'
class myException2(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'this is my exception 2'
def myfunc():
    try:
        raise myException2
        print('after exception')
    except myException:
        a = 'exception occur'
        print(a)
    else:
        a = 'exception doesn\'t occur'
        print(a)
    finally:
        a = 'no matter exception occurs or not'
        print(a)
        return a
```

Then runing myfunc() will output without any exception popping up

```
no matter exception occurs or not
```

But if the 'return a' code in finally clause in commented, the output will capture the unhandled myException2,

```
no matter exception occurs or not
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
myException2                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-29dfc9311b33> in <module>()
----> 1 myfunc()

<ipython-input-139-ba35768198b8> in myfunc()
      1 def myfunc():
      2     try:
----> 3         raise myException2
      4         print('after exception')
      5     except myException:

myException2: this is my exception 2
```

Why are the return code so important to do with the capturing of exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If finally is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The try
>   clause is executed, including any except and else clauses. If an
>   exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the
>   exception is temporarily saved. The finally clause is executed. If
>   there is a saved exception, it is re-raised at the end of the finally
>   clause. **If the finally clause raises another exception or executes a
>   return or break statement, the saved exception is discarded:**

This makes sense, because printing this error happens at the end of the finally statement. You explicitly exit the statement early, so that printing shouldn't be executed.