# How does this exception work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I want to know why `0` doesn't get printed when executing this function:

```
   def zeroDivision():
        try:
            try:
                raise Exception("0")
            finally:
                result = 5/0
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

I expected:

```
>>> zeroDivision()
0
integer division or modulo by zero
```

But instead I get:

```
>>> zeroDivision()
integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: probably related to good old `try: return x; finally: return y`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why return in function suppress the exception raised?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930809/why-return-in-function-suppress-the-exception-raised)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the Python language reference:](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

> If the `finally` clause raises another exception [in this case, `5/0`] or executes a return or break statement, the saved exception [in this case, the `Exception("0")`] is discarded